# how move an user from 1 OU to another OU in IBM LDAP

Tags: solaris, ldap

Does anyone have an idea how to move a user from 1 OU to another OU in IBM SDS LDAP?

Using command or via LDIF file?

From
Ou= Staff

To
OU=System

ID:
testuser1

Comment: Question is unclear: What is an OU? Is this a file that needs editing? …

Comment: organizational unit in ldap

Comment: Also it is not clear if from / to is what something needs to change from / to. Or the content of a file, or something else.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor it's LDAP. The only way I know is to use LDIF to export the entity and then reimport it, but that "feels" wrong